# Radio button value into another function

Tags: javascript, html

I am stuck with this code: I cannot get the value of a checked radio button to use in another function.

```
<script>
  function obtenerCD(browser) {
    document.getElementById('resultadoCD').innerHTML = browser;
    return browser;
  }

  function myFunction() {
      var a = "http://www.example.com/";
      var b = document.getElementById('variablea').value;
      var c = "/?Ancho=";
      var d = document.getElementById('variableb').value;
      var e = "%20M&Ancho%20Fraccion=";
      var f = document.getElementById('variablec').value;
      var g = "%20Cm";
      var h = "&Color%20Y%20Di%C3%A1metro=";
      var i = "Natural%2020-40%20Mm"; // variable inicial por defecto
      link = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i;

      /* inicio test area */
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = link;
      document.getElementById("boton").href = link;
    }
    /* fin test area */
</script>
<form>

  <p>
    (1) Elige la Altura:
    <select id="variablea" style="width:85px;" onchange="myFunction()">
      <option value="5-00-m">5.00 m</option>
      <option value="4-90-m">4.90 m</option>
      <option value="4-80-m">4.80 m</option>
      <option value="4-70-m">4.70 m</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="2-00-m" style "color:blue;">2.00 m *</option>
      <option value="1-90-m">1.90 m</option>
      <option value="1-80-m">1.80 m *</option>
    </select>
  </p>

  <p>
    (2) Elige el Ancho:
    <select id="variableb" style="width:90px;" onchange="myFunction()">
      <option value="1" selected="selected">1 metro</option>
      <option value="2">2 metros</option>
      <option value="3">3 metros</option>
      <option value="4">4 metros</option>
      <option value="5">5 metros</option>
      <option value="6">6 metros</option>
      <option value="7">7 metros</option>
      <option value="8">8 metros</option>
      <option value="9">9 metros</option>
      <option value="10">10 metros</option>
    </select>
    <select id="variablec" style="width:70px;" onchange="myFunction()">
      <option value="0" selected="selected">0 cm</option>
      <option value="10">10 cm</option>
      <option value="20">20 cm</option>
      <option value="30">30 cm</option>
      <option value="40">40 cm</option>
      <option value="50">50 cm</option>
      <option value="60">60 cm</option>
      <option value="70">70 cm</option>
      <option value="80">80 cm</option>
      <option value="90">90 cm</option>
    </select>
  </p>

  <p>
    (3) Elige el Color y el Di&aacute;metro:

    <div class="cd-selector">
      <input checked="checked" id="natural24" type="radio" name="browser" value="Natural%2020-40%20Mm" onclick="obtenerCD(this.value)">
      <label class="drinkcard-cc natural24" for="natural24">natural24</label>
      <input id="natural35" type="radio" name="browser" value="Natural%2030-50%20Mm" onclick="obtenerCD(this.value)">
      <label class="drinkcard-cc natural35" for="natural35">natural35</label>
      <input id="dorado24" type="radio" name="browser" value="Dorado%2020-40%20Mm" onclick="obtenerCD(this.value)">
      <label class="drinkcard-cc dorado24" for="dorado24">dorado24</label>
      <input id="dorado35" type="radio" name="browser" value="Dorado%2030-50%20Mm" onclick="obtenerCD(this.value)">
      <label class="drinkcard-cc dorado35" for="dorado35">dorado35</label>
    </div>
  </p>
  <p><a href="http://www.example.com" id="boton" />Aceptar</a>
  </p>
</form>
<p>--- Inicio test area ---</p>
<p>Link compuesto: <span id="demo"></span>
</p>
<p>Variable Color y Diametro: <span id="resultadoCD"></span>
</p>
<p>--- Fin test area ---</p>
```

Comment: Make sure you pass your code through a [validator](https://html5.validator.nu/) or [two](http://jshint.com/). There are some errors.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to get the value of a checked radio button is to use the querySelector method which takes a CSS-style selector as its parameter.

```
document.querySelector('input[name="browser"]:checked').value;
```

Comment: Thank you VKK. This has solved me the problem in a few seconds. Yesterday I spent 3 hours trying to figure it out as I am not really into coding as I wished. Have a nice day!

Comment: Awesome glad this helped! If this resolves your issue, please consider accepting the answer : )

Answer (score 0):

You are already reading the value in the function. The problem is when the page loads, even thought the checkbox is checked you are not seeing any value.

Reason being, checkbox already has `checked` attribute but the function is only called on `onclick`

```js
function obtenerCD(browser) {
  console.log(browser);
  document.getElementById('resultadoCD').innerHTML = browser;
}

document.getElementById('resultadoCD').innerHTML = document.querySelector('input[name="browser"]:checked').value;;
```

```html
<input checked="checked" id="natural24" type="radio" name="browser" value="Natural%2020-40%20Mm" onclick="obtenerCD(this.value)">
<label class="drinkcard-cc natural24" for="natural24">natural24</label>
<input id="natural35" type="radio" name="browser" value="Natural%2030-50%20Mm" onclick="obtenerCD(this.value)">
<label class="drinkcard-cc natural35" for="natural35">natural35</label>
<input id="dorado24" type="radio" name="browser" value="Dorado%2020-40%20Mm" onclick="obtenerCD(this.value)">
<label class="drinkcard-cc dorado24" for="dorado24">dorado24</label>
<input id="dorado35" type="radio" name="browser" value="Dorado%2030-50%20Mm" onclick="obtenerCD(this.value)">
<label class="drinkcard-cc dorado35" for="dorado35">dorado35</label>

<p>Variable Color y Diametro: <span id="resultadoCD"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you Sandeep! I have used the solution from VKK and it went perfectly! Have a nice day.